# how to get intersection point between two finite line segments

Tags: tcl

I went through all the links given in stack overflow to find the intersection between two line segments , but I was looking for TCL code to find intersection point between two line segments .

```
 The following code
  method lineLineIntersection { A B C1 C2 } { 
 # Line AB represented as a1x + b1y = c1 

  set afirst  [lindex $A 0]
  set asecond [lindex $A 1]
  set bfirst  [lindex $B 0]
  set bsecond [lindex $B 1]
  set cfirst  [lindex $C 0]
  set csecond [lindex $C 1]
  set dfirst  [lindex $D 0]
  set dsecond [lindex $D 1]

  set a1 [expr $bsecond  - $asecond] 
  set b1 [expr $afirst  - $bfirst] 
  set c1 [expr [expr ($a1 * $afirst)]  + [expr ($b1* $asecond)]]

  set a2 [expr $dsecond  -$csecond] 
  set b2 [expr $cfirst  - $dfirst]
  set p1 [expr $a2 * $cfirst]
  set p2 [expr $b2 * $csecond]

  set c2 [expr ($p1 + $p2)]

  set determinant [expr $a1*$b2 - $a2*$b1]
  set output [list]
  if { $determinant == 0 } {

  } else {
     set p1 [expr $b2 * $c1 ]
     set p2 [expr $b1 * ($c2) ]
     set diff [expr ($p1 - $p2)]
     set x  [expr $diff / $determinant]
     set p1 [expr ($a1 *$c2)]
     set p2 [expr ($a2 * $c1)]
     set diff [expr $p1 - $p2]
     set y  [expr $diff / $determinant]
     lappend output $x $y
  }
```

} 
   but it gives me intersection point of infinite line . I was looking for TCL code for intersection point between two finite lines

Comment: this package can help you ? [math::geometry](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/math/math_geometry.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tcllib has all sorts of useful routines within it, often implemented to be efficient. In particular, [the `math::geometry` package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/math/math_geometry.html) is helpful in this case, provided we express our line segments in the format it expects:

```
package require math::geometry

set lineSeg1 [list $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2]
set lineSeg2 [list $x3 $y3 $x4 $y4]
if {[math::geometry::lineSegmentsIntersect $lineSeg1 $lineSeg2]} {
    set interPt [math::geometry::findLineSegmentIntersection $lineSeg1 $lineSeg2]
    puts "the line segments intersect at ($interPt)"
} else {
    puts "the line segments don't intersect"
}
```